# Use variable value as Class property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a class A with some properties and a string x with a value. How can i lookup in Class A for a property name of variable x value?

```
class A {
    public int p1 {get;set;}
    public int p2 {get;set;}
    public int p3 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need reflection

```
var a = new A();
var x = "p1";
var prop = a.GetType().GetProperty(x);
// get value
var val = prop.GetValue(a);
// set value
prop.SetValue(a,123);
```